# Remapping Assembly

Tags: vb.net

My app was originally developed with VS2012. After some years, that installation became corrupted and I had to install VB2019. With this new version, I had to add the NuGet package “Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms” and use its new report viewer control to properly display the .rdlc reports used by this app.

Since the conversion, I now get the following warnings for three assemblies, "Microsoft SQL Server Types", "EnvDTE" and "Microsoft.VisualStudio.GraphModel" after each build:

Consider app.config remapping of assembly [AssemblyName, Culture, PublicKeyToken] from version [OldVersionNo] to version [NewVersionNo] after which it gives me the folder where that assembly is located.

The app.config file in my app contains minimal information and does not include any mention of these three assemblies. So how do I fix these warnings? I'm happy to provide the contents of my app.config file if needed.

Here is the full error message I am getting:

`Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" from Version "12.0.0.0" [C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types\12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll] to Version "14.0.0.0" [C:\DATA\StinsonSolutions\AppelateInnovations\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.14.0.314.76\lib\net40\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.`

`Consider app.config remapping of assembly "EnvDTE, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "7.0.3300.0" [] to Version "8.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\EnvDTE.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.`

`Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Microsoft.VisualStudio.GraphModel, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "11.0.0.0" [] to Version "14.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.GraphModel.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.`

Larry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to add some [Redirecting assembly versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions) instructions to your app.config file.

From the website:

> **Manually edit the app config file**: You can manually edit the app configuration file to resolve assembly issues. For example, if a
> vendor might release a newer version of an assembly that your app uses
> without supplying a publisher policy, because they do not guarantee
> backward compatibility, you can direct your app to use the newer
> version of the assembly by putting assembly binding information in
> your app's configuration file as follows.

```
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="someAssembly" publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1" culture="en-us" />  
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

So, for you, this would be (I have shown the full Xml hierarchy below) :

```
<config>
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />  
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="EnvDTE" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />  
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.GraphModel" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />  
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
</config>
```

If you have other sections in your app.config file, then you just need to add the <assemblyBinding> section at the end of your file.

<strike>If you add the full error message, I would be happy to update the answer with full information.</strike>

Comment: Thanks, JayV, I have added the full error messages above. If you need my current app.config file, let me know (there isn't much there).

Larry

Comment: @LarryStinson I've updated my answer to refer to the assembly version numbers you added. Hope it works well for you.